# Horizontal background css position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set only horizontal background property , adding `background-position-x` works in chrome , safari, IE. but FF and Opera not supporting

I want to add dynamic left value of position

```
var ppp = 10px;
var pLeft = ppp+' top";
jQuery(".bg-test").css("background-position" , pLeft );
```

Update

```
var ppp = jQuery(".someClass").width();
var pLeft = ppp+' top";
jQuery(".bg-test").css("background-position" , pLeft );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5dj/6/#run

Comment: please tell us in more details and allow us to show your html code and let us know what you actually need. Yes, its possible to add dynamic value as position for a value.

Comment: why can't you use `background-position: 10px top;`? if it's something to do with the jquery (don't get where this fits in as it's not in your fiddle) you're `ppp` var needs quotes and `pLeft` has mixed quotes

Comment: left position is dynamic. I just used 10px for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.bg-test').css('backgroundPosition','left top');
```

Or with a dynamic value:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var leftPos = 10+2+5+'px';
    $('.bg-test').css('background-position', leftPos +' bottom');
});
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/hQ5dj/8/)

Comment: well, I want left position to be dynamic which comes from some width calculation

Comment: Well it was just an example, you can also use dynamic values - see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/hQ5dj/10/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`background: url(http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1035/human_o2/128/object_rotate_left.png) 100px 0px no-repeat #cc0;` ,

see http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5dj/9/